# Authentication Failed using Private Key, Public Key

Tags: ios, swift, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

We are trying to connect our Mac and AWS servers using the private key. But every time we got *authentication failed*.
Also, we have checked both keys on another application and it's working fine.
Can you please help?

Library Link - https://github.com/Frugghi/SwiftSH

```
self.authenticationChallenge = .byPublicKeyFromFile(username: self.username, password: "", publicKey: "", privateKey: pvtfilePath?.relativePath ?? "")
self.shell = try? SSHShell(host: self.hostname, port: self.port ?? 22, terminal: "vanilla")
self.shell.withCallback { [unowned self] (string: String?, error: String?) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let string = string {
                        self.appendToTextView(string)
                    }
                    if let error = error {
                        self.appendToTextView("[ERROR] \(error)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .connect()
            .authenticate(self.authenticationChallenge)
            .open { [unowned self] (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    self.appendToTextView("[ERROR] \(error)")
                    self.textView.isEditable = false
                } else {
                    self.textView.isEditable = true
                }                
            }
```